# On Android browser, the whole page jumps up and down when typing inside a textbox?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

When I first focus on the textbox, the page jumps down  (auto scroll).

Then, when I push keys to type, the page keeps jumping (auto scroll) up and down.

Why is that? It's fine on the iPhone and web.

Comment: in my experience it's when the site is either too intense for the phone or there are lots of `position:fixed;` kind of elements that always want to stay somewhere related to the page

Comment: @ProfSmiles absolutely right ! it was the "fixed".

Comment: I'll add an answer for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a site has a `position:fixed;` css attribute on an element it is locked to a certain part of the page in reference to the browser window, so opening the keyboard changes the window size and therefore the positions of said elements. If you're writing a site you know will be used via mobile, don't use `position:fixed;` on inputs!

Comment: It also happens if the site has position:absolute. In my case a div had text boxes and typing in them was creating this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-transform: none;`

on the parent div fixed it for me. Android is buggy :/

But this is only true if you are adding webkit transform to parent divs to fix other android webkit bugs.

This is not a fix if you are using position: fixed. I have no position: fixed elements.

Answer (score 0):

This can be linked to you z-indexes if you've got absolute and fixed divs: I've written the following rule: a fixed div have to have a higher z-index than ANY absolute div in the page.

More info here:
http://java-cerise.blogspot.fr/2012/02/android-browser-jumping-up-and-down.html

Hope this helps.